# How/where to acquire public data on fears/phobias?

Tags: data-request

What's a good way to get data on what people are afraid of by geography?

I looked into possible ways:

1. Obtain search ranking of questions like 'afraid of spiders' on keywordtool 
   https://keywordtool.io/search/google/14515792?keyword=afraid%20of&country=uk&language=en#suggestions
2. Get google trend ranking Arachnophobia

What would be the most sound method to get data on phobia?